# create a SharePoint list using a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's my code. It validates, but btn on click doesn't do anything.

```
<button onclick="createList()">Click here to create a list</button>
<script>
function createList() {

    var siteUrl="https://www.sharepoint.aspx";
    var clientCtx= new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    alert(oWebsite);
    var listCreationInfo=new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title('CustomList');
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.announcements);

    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

    clientCtx.load(oList);
    clientCtx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
  }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
alert("result");
  var result=oList.get_title()+ ' created.':
  alert(result);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_messge() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in your browser debug console in there and see where it's failing or if it is getting called at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have below typing mistakes in your code also.

- you have written `var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();` but your context variable name is `clientCtx`. So this line should be `var oWebsite = clientCtx.get_web();`
- you have written `:` instead of `;` in success function (before the alert)

Refer below code it should work :

**Note: Please replace `siteUrl` with your site url.**

```
function createList() {
  var siteUrl = "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite"; //use your site url here
  var clientCtx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oWebsite = clientCtx.get_web();
  alert(oWebsite);
  var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
  listCreationInfo.set_title('CustomList');
  listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.announcements);
  this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
  clientCtx.load(oList);
  clientCtx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
  alert("result");
  var result = oList.get_title() + ' created.'; alert(result);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_messge() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: I'm very new to JS, still lots of learning ahead. I made those changes, but the site URL is that the URL of where I create a new list or where I want to view the new list in a page?

Comment: No problem ...just tell me if you are creating list in the same site or any sub site.

Comment: If you are creating list in the same site and not the sub site then just write "var clientCtx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();" . You do not have to pass the URL here...it will be useful to get context of current site.